# yarn - Proper way to quickly check if `package.json` and `yarn.lock` requirements are satisfied?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-lock.json

I'd like to verify whether all the dependencies in my project (`package.json` and `yarn.lock`) are satisfied without having to run `yarn install` (which builds out a whole dependency tree and makes network requests)

At first, I was very hopeful that `yarn check` did this. The following command verifies that each dependency is satisfied in `package.json` **and** verifies that the installed package matches the `yarn.lock` file.

```
yarn check --integrity --verify-tree
```

However, [the documentation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check) says this is deprecated as of yarn v2, and that `yarn install --check-files` should be used instead.

But [the documentation for `--check-files`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-check-files) makes it seem like this does something completely different.

> ## yarn install --check-files
>
> Verifies that already installed files in node_modules did not get removed.

I can also verify that running it essentially runs a full `yarn install` command, so it's not useful here.

Furthermore, the [pull request that removed `yarn check`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/pull/106/files#r2304389370) also mentions that the behavior of `--check-files` isn't exactly intuitive.

**So what's the supported way of running this check in yarn v2 and later?** Is there any way to do a lightweight check against `package.json` and `yarn.lock` without having to build out the whole dependency tree over a network like `yarn install` does?

FWIW, [a similar question was asked for `npm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894812/check-if-package-json-contains-dependencies-not-in-node-modules) and the solution was to use the `--dry-run` flag, but that flag doesn't seem to exist in `yarn`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options in the [yarn cli](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/) which probably give you the ability to achieve what you want to do.

My best guess is to use the [offline mode](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-offline) to stop any external requests, which you asked for. The [frozen lockfile](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-frozen-lockfile) additionally gives you the option to error out in case the dependencies are not in sync with each other.

The option to [check files](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-check-files) that you mention is not inherently needed for your case, as far as I understand, because you don't want to check the `node_modules`-folder rather than the `package.json` and the `yarn.lock`.

So how about `yarn install --offline --frozen-lockfile`?

Best wishes, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks so much! The `--offline` feature didn't have much explanation in that documentation but is better explained [here](https://yarnpkg.com/features/offline-cache). However, it looks like it maintains a separate cache folder. This isn't ideal, I would think there would still be an easier way to check installation. But this is a great thing to investigate.

Comment: `--offline` appears to have been retired in Yarn 3.  Any idea what might have replaced it?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the `--dry-run` flag for `npm` does what you are looking for in `yarn`. [Starting with `npm@7.0.0`, `npm` parses and uses `yarn.lock` files](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/621733939456933888/npm-v7-series-why-keep-package-lockjson) if they exist (and there's no `package-lock.json`).

So you can use `npm` with the `--dry-run` option and it should work with a `yarn.lock` file.

Make sure you are using `npm 7.0.0` or later. To update: `npm install -g npm`